# Solving an ODE via a 5th order Taylor polynomial expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Furthermore, we have initial conditions $y(1)=5$ and $y'(0)=3$

Letting $y= \Sigma_{k=0}^5 c_kx^k$ we can rewrite our differential equation as:

$\Sigma_{k=2}^5 c_k(k)(k-1)x^k-\Sigma_{k=1}^5 4c_kkx^k + \Sigma_{k=0}^5 4c_kx^k=0$

The initial condition $y'(0)=3$ leads us to $c_1=3$

The initial condition $y(1)=5$ gives us that $c_0+c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5=5$

Now, using the method of matching coefficients I've found that

$a_2=0$

$a_3=0$

$a_4=D$ (arbitrary)

$a_5=0$

$c_0 + 3 + D = 5$

$\rightarrow 2-D=c_0$

However an online calculator is telling me that the solution is $y=2x^4+3x$. However, the online calculator is giving an exact answer whilst I'm using a degree $5$ taylor polynomial.

Can anyone see something I did wrong? General insight appreciated.

Comment: Why do you switch between $c_k$ and $a_k$? Where did you evaluate the coefficient equations for degree 0 and 1?

Comment: centered at $a=0$?  you mean centered at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matching coefficients, along with the initial conditions, gives you a $6\times6$system of equations

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_0\\c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\c_4\\c_5
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\5\\0\\0\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the first two equations are from the initial conditions and the last four are from equating coefficients. 5 of these immediately give us coefficients and this allows us to solve the remaining equation for $c_4=2$.

So somewhere you got that $c_4$ should be arbitrary and missed that the equation implying $c_0=0$.

This a specific case of a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation), which can be more quickly solved by guessing that solutions are of the form $y=x^m$.